# Compare a string with a value in android sqllite

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to compare a string with the food name in the SQLite database, but I think the query has some error.

```
public Cursor selectfood(String food_pick){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT food,calorie FROM foodDatabase WHERE food = "+food_pick,null);
    return res;
}
```

It is throwing the following Exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.nlss.custom_diet, PID: 1990
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "khichdi": syntax error (code 1): , 
while compiling: SELECT food,calorie FROM foodDatabase WHERE food = Dal khichdi ,1 cup
```

Is there any other alternative to write this `SELECT` statement?

Comment: Add d single quote to compare string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT food,calorie FROM foodDatabase WHERE food = '"+food_pick+ "'",null);
```

try to use this, you havn't added single quote i think

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with my database table

Comment: you have modified database structure please update database version and name. this will resolved your error, uninstall and then install the app again.

Comment: return res; res:SQLiteCursor@568....On using debugger this is what that is being shown. I hope "res" has the matching name in it

Comment: The query did help.@Bharat singh

Comment: This will blow up when the value contains a quote.

Comment: Any other way to prevent this blow up? @CL

Comment: [sqlEscapeString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#sqlEscapeString(java.lang.String)), or better an SQL parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following query :

```
Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT food,calorie FROM foodDatabase WHERE food = '"+food_pick + "'",null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You query is missing the '' for the selection argument string value.

```
Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT food,calorie FROM foodDatabase WHERE food ='"+ food_pick + "'",null);
```

Comment: This will blow up when the value contains a quote.